# How can I layout a dynamic width of grid children with CustomScrollView capabilities?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I layout a dynamic width of grid children with CustomScrollView capabilities?

The children of the grid are of type Text with softWrap property set to false, as I don't want to have the Text data being laid out on multiple lines and change the height of the Text widget.

But I can't have this setup using SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent hence its CrossAxis has a fixed width.

Here is an example of the layout that I need to do.

[image: Sample layout]

The Text Widgets should have a fixed height and dynamic width and if the line need to span multiple lines the layout should permit this like the RED TEXT in the sample layout.

What Widget (or custom package) you guys recommend to use in this layout design?

Many thanks for your help

Here is my current code:

```
CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverGrid(
                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                        buildPage(myData), // => List<Text> Text  has (softWrap: false,)
                      ),
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                        maxCrossAxisExtent: 60.0,
                        childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: Hi @skyslar7, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Found it --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74170550/flutter-wrap-row-of-expanded-widgets

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use flexible in Flutter. It make width or height dynamic. Here documentation for flexible:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html

You need to design your layout. When I look at your image,

- First use column for up to down design or Use ListView/GridView
- Second use row with flexible
- Third put your item in flexible widget

Flexible will make your layout like you want. You can search flexible use or watch flexible from flutter widget of week.